# Average arrays to same fixed length

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple arrays with different length and I would like this data to be averaged to comparable arrays, e.g.

```
array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
target_length = 3
def cast(array, target_length):
    ...
```

This should give `cast(array1, target_length)` as:

`np.array([(1+2*0.66)/1.66, (2*0.33+3*1+4*0.33)/1.66, (4*0.66+5)/1.66 ])`

because: 5/3=1.66. Also we would obtain:
`cast(array1, target_length)` as:

`np.array([(1+2*0.33)/1.33, (2*0.66+3*0.66)/1.33, (3*0.33+4)/1.33])`

because: 4/3=1.33.

The arrays will never need to grow as a good `numpy` solution is available for this.

Is there a solution using the `numpy` library?

Comment: What is the generic formula you would apply? What when the array needs to grow, what if it's target length is 1, ...

Comment: You need to be a little more clear, not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated my answer. The arrays will not grow. The policy is to divide array length by the `target_length` to obtain a threshold and then to add the values partially until the threshold is obtained.

Comment: Could you explain more about the formula you want to use. Maybe just make it step-by-step on one of your input arrays. Also what would be the expected result of `cast(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 3)`? Where the larget_length is an even divisor of the current length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question could be be read in a few different ways, but if I got it right, what you are trying to achieve is

```
def cast(array, target_length):
    target = np.zeros(target_length)
    for i in range(target_length*len(array)):
        target[i//len(array)] += array[i//target_length]/len(array)
    return target
```

If that's what you are aiming for, this may be obtained through `numpy` operations as

```
def cast(array, target_length):
    return np.mean(np.repeat(array, target_length).reshape(-1, len(array)), 1)
```

Comment: The question asks "Is there a solution using the numpy library?" and your answer is basically: "no", right?

Comment: @MSeifert: Since they want to get an `np.array` as the return type, avoiding `numpy` will probably be tough, no matter which solution you may come up with. (I updated the answer to make that explicit without changing the calculation.)

Comment: It's not about the return type, it's more about the vectorization of the problem. Your solution will be slower on numpy-arrays than on python lists. That's what makes it a non-numpy-solution in my eyes.

Comment: The `numpy`-only solution is great!

Comment: I added what could be called a non-non-numpy solution. It does indeed perform quite a bit better on large arrays.